# Spring @Retryable with configurable delay based on client

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, spring-retry

I am developing a Spring boot application. From my application we are calling an external RestService and want to retry if RestCall fails for any reason.

I know that `@Retryable` within spring should take care of this. I am trying to implement something like below with parameters:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts=3,value=RunTimeException.class,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 900000))
```

Now my problem is, there are multiple clients who will call this service. When client1 is calling this service, i want to retry when a failure occurs after 15min. When client2 is calling this service, i want to retry when a failure occurs after 1sec.

So i want to know if there is any way we can configure the delay in retryable based on client1 or client2.

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ThreadLocal<Long>` `@Bean` to store the delay and then use `delayExpression="@threadLocalBean.get()`.

However, suspending a thread for 15 minutes is a bit severe.

You would be better using a scheduler for the retries in that case.